# Find Eigenspace/Eigenvalue for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am currently taking a basic 100 level linear algebra class, and we just went over how to find eigenspace and eigenvalue for a matrix. But on our homework, a question says

`Suppose that λ is an eigenvalue of T : V → V, show blah blah`

Since a linear transformation can be written as a matrix, can I just think of it as solving for eigenvalue/space of a matrix? Is there anything fundamentally different? Thank you!

Comment: Well, whether or not you can (or should) think of $T$ as a matrix depends on what the "blah blah" is

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "Show that the corresponding
eigenspace is a T-invariant subspace of V." --- I know to show it's a subspace, I need to show T is not an empty set, and show addition and scale multiplication still in T. But I am not sure what it means by an eigenvalue of a linear transformation. We only talk about matrices with eigenvalue/space.

Comment: You mean that you need to show that **V** is a subspace (that it's closed under addition and multiplication by scalars).  You also need to show that it's **T-invariant**, which is something you should look up in your notes or textbook.  "$V$ is $T$-invariant" means that for any $v \in V$, $T(v)$ is also in $V$.

Comment: This is a question where anything you might do to write $T$ as an explicit matrix or "compute the eigenvalues/eigenspaces" is besides the point.  A question like this comes down purely to understanding the definitions at play here, and how they fit together.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you! I will try to understand it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hi, sorry for bothering you. I wish you can comment on if my understanding is correct or not. --- T(v) is a linearly transformation with respect to vector v. Tv is a matrix multiplies the v vector. Two are the same thing. For example, if I can write T(u) ∈ U, then I can write Tu ∈ U? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, those are the same.  When $T$ is a linear transformation, both notations can be used; $Tv$ means $T(v)$.